# calling exe performance cost (compared to DLL)

Tags: c++, performance

We were discussing the possibility of using an exe instead of DLL inside a C or C++ code. The idea would be that in some cases to use an exe and pass arguments to it. (I guess its equivalent to somehow loading its main function as if it was a DLL).
The question we were wondering is does it imply a performance cost (especially in a loop with more than one iteration).
I tried to look in existing threads, while nobody answered this specific question. I saw that calling a function from DLL had an **overhead for the first call**, but then subsequent calls would **only take 1 or 2 instructions**.
For the exe case, it will each time need to create a **separate process** so it can run.(a second process if I need to open a shell that would open it, but from my research I can do it wihtout calling a shell). This process creation should cost some performance I'd guess. Moreover I think that the exe will **each time be loaded into RAM**, destroyed at the end of the process, then reloaded for next call and so on. A problem that is not present (?) with DLL.
PS: we were discussing this question more on a theoretical level than for implementing it, it's a question for the sake of learning.

Comment: There's about a factor 10000 difference in call overhead. This might still not matter when the actual work takes seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, a DLL is going to get loaded, and if you call to it many times in a short time, it will have a benefit. If the time between calls is long enough, the DLL content may get evicted from RAM and have to be loaded from disk again (yes, that's hard to specify, and partly depends on the memory usage on the system).

However, executable files do get cached in memory, so the cost of "loading the executable" isn't that big. Yes, you have to create a new process and destroy it at the end, with all the related memory management code. For a small executable, this will be relatively light work, for a large, complex executable, it may be quite a long time.

Bear in mind that executing the same program many times isn't unusual - compiling a large project or running some sort of script on a large number of files, just to give a couple of simple examples. So the performance of this will be tuned by OS developers.

Obviously, the "retain stuff in RAM" applies to both DLL and EXE - it's basic file-caching done by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

The costs of running an exe are tremendous compared to calling a function from a DLL. If you can do it with a DLL, the you should if performance matters.

Of course, there may be other factors to consider: For example, when there is a bug in the code called, and crashes the process, in the case of an exe it is merely that exe that goes down, and the caller survives, but if the bug is in a DLL, the caller crashes, too.